# Having used Kirsch's filter for segmentation of blood vessels, I want to remove an unwanted part

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I've used Kirsch's filter to obtain the following result, but I want to remove the circular detection (which aren't actually vessels) which I've pointed with a red arrow below:

[image]

How do I go about removing the circular detection, which is not a blood vessel? Here's the code for the current segmentation:

```
h1 = np.array([[5, -3, -3], [5, 0, -3], [5, -3, -3]], dtype=np.float32)/ 15
h2 = np.array([[-3, -3, 5], [-3, 0, 5], [-3, -3, 5]], dtype=np.float32) / 15
h3 = np.array([[-3, -3, -3], [5, 0, -3], [5, 5, -3]], dtype=np.float32) / 15
h4 = np.array([[-3, 5, 5], [-3, 0, 5], [-3, -3, -3]], dtype=np.float32) / 15
h5 = np.array([[-3, -3, -3], [-3, 0, -3], [5, 5, 5]], dtype=np.float32) / 15
h6 = np.array([[5, 5, 5], [-3, 0, -3], [-3, -3, -3]], dtype=np.float32) / 15
h7 = np.array([[-3, -3, -3], [-3, 0, 5], [-3, 5, 5]], dtype=np.float32) / 15
h8 = np.array([[5, 5, -3], [5, 0, -3], [-3, -3, -3]], dtype=np.float32) / 15
```

My desired result is something like this (note that this segmentation is of a different image):

[image]

Comment: you can try using houghcircles (for detection and removal of the circular boundaries)

Answer (score 0):

I would try with thresholding the first image (plain Otsu method may suffice) and selecting only those objects, that are visible on both images. This circle is pretty bright, whereas veins (?) are dark.

Comment: Wouldn't threshold give me only the circle? I need only the vessels.

Comment: It depends on threshold, you might find a threshold or thresholding algorithm that shows only dark parts.

Out of curiosity: have you tried Sauvola thresholding on those pictures? Seems to me that Sauvola with large mask may work for this type of images.